# SSRS login failure after DB restore

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

In SSRS I have a shared Data Source where the authentication is set to "Credentials stored securely in the report server" and my reports were authenticating correctly and running as expected.

After restoring the DB from a backup, it seems to have "broken" the user permissions. I checked that the user has "connect" permissions on the server AND "select" permissions on the DB that was restored.

Also, I can successfully login through sql server management studio with the user in question. But when I try to Test the connection on the SSRS Data Source it fails.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the credentials in ssrs? Perhaps the restore was from a point in time before the credentials were being stored securely on the server. Is redeploying the report an option?

Comment: Yeah, I've checked the credentials a hundred times and I've tried creating a brand new shared data source from scratch, but the [Test Connection] fails and the reports fail. If I enter a different user it works, but was trying to avoid creating new sql users each time this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time @Ross Bush, I found another post on stackoverflow that was somewhat related and I was able to fix the issue. I just ran this sql and it fixed the problem:

```
BEGIN
exec sp_change_users_login 'Update_one', '<username>', '<username>'
END
```

I'll just run this after restore to make sure it doesn't happen again.